# Ошибка "не удалось создать имя ресурса"

Tags: c#

При копировании проекта в другое место на жестком диске возникает ошибка в проекте:

[image: список ошибок]

Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

1. перезапустить Visual Studio,
2. выбрать другой путь (короче и без пробелов),
3. исключить форму (правый клик - исключить из проекта), по которой идет ошибка, из проекта,
4. удалить вообще все лишнее из проекта.

Comment: разместил в корень диска, перезапустил, не помогло. Исключить форму Form1 (с которой проблемы) не получается, при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши отсутствует возможность  исключить из проекта, а для Form2 и Form3 такая возможность есть( с ними то все нормально).
В проекте кажется ничего лишнего нету, или что вы под этим понимаете?

Answer (score 0):

В вы не дебаг запускайте, а сборку решения. Что-то типа Ctrl+shift+b

Comment: Проект работает и его можно запустить. А вот Form1 не открывается. а следовательно и изменения нельзя внести.

Comment: Сборка решения? Есть построение решения, но это не решает проблемы.